# .run() on Apex class

Tags: apex, trigger

Apologies if this is a trivial query but I have not been able to find an answer for this query in my online search.

This is the code written for Task Trigger (*all are currently working as expected*)

```
trigger Task on Task (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, 
   before insert, before update) {

    new TriggerHandler().run();
}
```

This is the helper class below

```
public without sharing class TriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {

    protected override void beforeInsert() {
        TaskUtil.adjust((List<Task>) trigger.new, (Map<Id, Task>) trigger.oldmap);
    }
    
    protected override void afterInsert() {}

    protected override void afterUpdate() {
        TaskUtil.onUpdate((List<Task>) trigger.new, (Map<Id, Task>) trigger.oldmap);
        
    }

    protected override void beforeUpdate() {
        TaskUtil.onTaskUpdate((List<Task>) trigger.new, (Map<Id, Task>) trigger.oldmap);
        
    }

}
```

In the trigger, the helper class is being called `new TriggerHandler().run()`

I am not able to find any documentation for this **.run()** method

Can someone throw any pointers as to what this .run() method does ?

Comment: This is custom code. That means we can't tell you what it does, or if it even has documentation. In general, these frameworks do something to initialize themselves during `new TriggerHandler()`, and then have a method called `run` or `execute` that handles the business logic. If you look in your org, you should find the class. If you share it, we can describe what it does.

Comment: How can this `TriggerHandler` class extend itself?